# Why the OS is not booting up?

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, firmware

Manjaro Linux unable to boot up.

Error msg

```
[ 0.000000] [firmware Bug] : TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0X25 (or later)
```

---

[image]

Comment: There's no error in that screenshot. The firmware bug was detected and a feature was disable. It then seemingly gets stuck while checking the disks. It looks like you have issues with the disk. If you wait, it may well continue booting later. _Then_ yes, it may be a good idea to update the BIOS, but there's nothing here saying that the BIOS is causing the boot to get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

## Regarding the error message:

> ```
> [ 0.000000] [firmware Bug] : TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0X25 (or later)
> ```

- Option 1

  Update your BIOS.
- Option 2

  If there is no newer BIOS version for your machine, you need to have Intel Microcode installed:

  ```
    sudo apt-get install intel-microcode
  ```

---

## Regarding your quote:

> Manjaro Linux unable to boot up.

If it is stuck at the file system check, as said by Kusalananda, you may have an issue with your system drive.

Comment: Where to write this command,actually I'm not able to enter into the OS.

Comment: @yank000002 Try putting your system drive to another computer and investigate if it's faulty.